# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. am unable to findout the solution plz help me

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

this is my problem i unable to find out the solution

ADD TODO file

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { nanoid } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

const AddTodo = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const [name, setname] = useState('')

    const handleChange = (e)=>{
            setname(e.target.value)
    }
    const handleSubmit = (e)=>{
          e.preventDefault()
          dispatch(AddTodo({id:nanoid(),todo:name,completed:false}))
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form  >
                <input type="text" name="input" value={name}  onChange={handleChange} />
                <button onClick={handleSubmit} >Add Todo</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddTodo
```

add todo slice file

```
import {createSlice, createEntityAdapter  } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const todoAdapter = createEntityAdapter()
export const todoSelectors = todoAdapter.getSelectors((state)=>state.todos)

const todoSlice = createSlice({
    name:'todos',
    initialState: todoAdapter.getInitialState(),
    reducers:{
        addTodo:todoAdapter.addOne,
    }
})
export const {addTodo} = todoSlice.actions

export default todoSlice.reducer;
```

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import todoSlice from './todoSlice';
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {todos:todoSlice}
})
export default store;
```

please some one help me i am unable to find out that

please

Comment: What file is the error is in? Can you include a snapshot of the error in your question as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below code

```
 dispatch(AddTodo({id:nanoid(),todo:name,completed:false}))
```

`AddTodo` is referring to your function component itself.
You probably meant to do something like:

```
dispatch("AddTodo", {id:nanoid(), todo:name, completed:false})
```

where `"AddTodo"` is name of your action and `{id:nanoid(), todo:name, completed:false}` being the payload.